# Send notification e-mail when php form is sent

Tags: php, forms

If a php form is completed and send with the submit button, how can I send an e-mail together to an administrator for example? I want to sent the user's name who created a new user through a form

The creator is coming from `$_SESSION['username']`.

Can I use the PHP mail function to do this?

Comment: yes you can, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Before asking this question, if you have some idea of a function that you may be able to use, you should really read the documentation for said function first. [mail()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 1):

If `mail` is correctly set up in your php.ini file you can use this.

You can also install and use `PHPMailer` if you want access to a full SMTP server or a lot more fine control over how your email is built.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the mail function. You just have to send the input field value's from the form in the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've posted a rather simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605687/simple-way-to-send-email-with-javascript-and-php/15606089#15606089) on SO before which you can take a look at, also there are numerous examples elsewhere on the internet that provide you details for the task.