# Creating a Contact form

Tags: php, html, contacts, contact-form

I don't know much about PHP coding. I have this contact form:

http://jsfiddle.net/HtU4D/

```
<div id="content">
   <h1> Contact me </h1>

    <form action=" " method="post"  autocomplete="on">
        <p> <label for="username" class="iconic user" > Name <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  required="required" placeholder="Hi friend, how may I call you ?"  /> </p>

        <p> <label for="usermail" class="iconic mail-alt"> E-mail address <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="email" name="usermail" id="usermail" placeholder="I promise I hate spam as much as you do" required="required"  /> </p>

        <p> <label for="usersite" class="iconic link"> Website </label> <input type="url" name="usersite" id="usersite"  placeholder="eg: http://www.miste.com" /> </p>

        <p> <label for="subject" class="iconic quote-alt"> Subject </label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"  placeholder="What would you like to talk about?" /> </p>

        <p> <label for="message" class="iconic comment"> Message  <span class="required">*</span></label> <textarea placeholder="Don't be shy, live me a friendly message and I'll answer as soon as possible "  required="required" ></textarea> </p>
        <p class="indication"> All fields with a <span class="required">*</span> are required</p>

        <input type="submit" value=" ★  Send the mail !" />     

    </form>     
</div>
```

I want the " Send the mail !" button to send the details directly to my email.

What files should I make? The contact form file is already a PHP file but I don't know what to add !

Sorry for my bad English, 
Let me know if you didn't understand my Question!

Comment: Put in short - on server-side (in PHP for example) you have to get the values from the `form`, sanitize them, and use them in the `mail()` function to send the email. But your question is too broad for StackOverflow, there are plenty of sources and tutorials on Internet on how-to.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `PHP` `mail()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. And your `form action=" "` should point to a `.php` file that will grab the `POST` values from the form.

Comment: You need a script on the server (something like FormMail see http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html) to process the data received from the form.

Comment: Anticipating: in my opinion, there is anything wrong with this question (+1 from me). It is polite, and it has fiddle. It can be a possible duplicate, but there is no reason to downvote.

Comment: @Jacek — The downvote arrow is marked "The question does not show any research". There's no sign that the OP has bothered to learn the first thing about PHP.

Comment: OK. You are right in that case. Thx for the information, and after a while I think this is true, it does not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a PHP file like mail.php. In the form you will direct to that file.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
```

In the mail.php you will verify the inputs:

```
$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
```

It means that if username is actually set then `$username` will get that value, the empty string otherwise.

Using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). You should do this for all the inputs.

If you don't want to use the ternary operator (which I highly recommend though) then you can do this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
}
else
{
    $username = "";
}
```

If you're satisfied with all the inputs then you can use the built in [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send the email.

Once completed you can redirect the user back:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

I've answered a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605687/simple-way-to-send-email-with-javascript-and-php/15606089#15606089) question before which you can feel free to look at, there are also plenty of resources on the internet that will help you.

Comment: -1 for using the ternary operator. Altough correct it isn't a nice coding style. And especially difficult for a beginner.

Comment: What, -1 for using the ternary operator? Explain yourself, how is if bool then stuff else stuff better? IT's a mess for many variables.

Comment: I said that is `especially` difficult for a beginner start with `if else` or something

Comment: I gave a link so OP could look at it, I'm teaching him a better way to do something and you down vote me, that's just wrong.

Comment: I don't why people are giving minus vote

Comment: Be honest did you learn the ternary before if else? Atleast add if else too you'll get an upvote

Comment: I disagree with up or down voting over an opinion to use one or the other. Even if OP would be a beginner. It is still a good / not a good answer if you use one or the other.

Comment: Thank you, and true I did use if else at first but I thought providing the link would be enough, now nothing should go wrong.